# Petersen Exercise 1.61 - flat square torus

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

The following is  Exercise 1.61 of Peter Petersen's Riemannian Geometry (2016):

> Show that the **flat square torus**
> $$T^2=\Bbb R^2/\Bbb Z^2=\left(S^1,\frac{1}{4\pi^2}d\theta^2\right)\times \left(S^1,\frac{1}{4\pi^2}d\theta^2\right).$$

Is the RHS a flat torus?

Comment: Yes: it is the Riemannian product of two flat manifolds, since 1 dimensional manifolds are indeed flat

Comment: I thought the 4-tuple map is the flat torus and this one is not.

Comment: I don't understand what means "the 4-tuple map". A flat torus is a torus (i.e a manifold diffeomorphic to $S^1\times S^1$ endowed with some flat metric (i.e with constant curvature 0). The RHS is such a manifold

Comment: Sorry. I meant $(x,y)\mapsto(\cos x , \sin x, \cos y, \sin y)$.

Comment: I see. This map goes to the quotient and gives a diffeomorphism $\Bbb R^2 / (2\pi \Bbb Z)^2 \simeq S^1\times S^1$. Show that the pullback metric of the restriction of the euclidean metric on the RHS is exactly what Petersen wrote, up to the $4\pi^2$ constant (this is just a rescaling to have $\Bbb R / \Bbb Z$ instead of $\Bbb R / 2\pi \Bbb Z$)

Comment: Also : your example is *a* flat torus. There are infinitely many flat tori that are pariwise non-isometric (nor a rescaling of each other, nor conformal). The one you exhibited is the *square* flat torus since the two simple closed geodesics are orthogonal and of same length

Comment: Really? other than in conformal class? Give me some idea of that torus please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134991/discussion-between-didier-and-c-f-g).